# How do I set up an iAd that works for both iOS 5 and 6? and if possible compatible with all iOS

Tags: ios, iad

I tried adding ads to my app but none show up I don't know why, I think its because the ad code I used is not compatible with the iOS I'm testing it on. Here is my code:

```
@implementation Class_ScoreViewController
{
    ADBannerView *_bannerView;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view addSubview:_bannerView];
}
```

i do have the `<AdBannerViewDelegate>`

or if I'm doing it wrong how do I do it correctly?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You've added the delegate but you're not setting it. Before [super ViewDidLoad] type _bannerView.delegate = self;

Comment: It's still not working :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is a general problem. Many people are reporting that their ads are not showing.

Implement these method from AdBannerViewDelegate protocol:

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner;
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

And check if (NSError *)error is returning

```
Ad inventory unavailable" UserInfo=0x49a4f0 {ADInternalErrorCode=3, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad inventory unavailable
```

It so, try again in a few hours!

Comment: Yeah thats the error I'm getting but it has been going on for a while now, what else can i do?

Comment: Yeah the problem seems to be with apple for what i've been researching :/